# Python, Tkinter - How to get text from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I apologize if this question has been asked before but i have been trying to solve this problem by myself and with the help of my classmates. They seem to have no problem but i just cant get to the `Value` of an `Entry`. I always get strange strings like `<function StringVar.get at 0x0358E970>` or similar. I have spent full 5 hours now trying to solve this with the help of the internet too. I hope there is someone out there who can help me understand this.

So I have this `class` with a function in which i create a Tkinter window with one simple entry and one simple button. But when i try to get the value of the `textvariable` i dont get a `string` but some kind of code i cant work with at all. What am i doing wrong? Or is there something i am not doing?

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import *

    class StrWnd:
        def __init__(self):
            self.firstname = StringVar
        def Register(self):
            self.register = Toplevel(self.scr)
            self.register.geometry("300x300")
            self.register.title("Register")

            Label(self.register, text="Vorname(Keine Nummern)").pack()
            ttk.Entry(self.register, textvariable=self.firstname).pack()

            ttk.Button(self.register, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.printValues()).pack()

        def printValues(self):
            print(self.firstname.get)
```

**Any tips are welcome.**

Comment: it's `.get()`, not `.get`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know that I have no brackets there but that is actually necessary. If I add brackets i get the error `print(self.firstname.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: @BryanOakley if I also add self into the brackets i get the error `value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name)
AttributeError: 'StrWnd' object has no attribute '_tk'`

Comment: `StringVar` also has to be `StringVar()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley then I get the error `self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are many problems in your code.

To answer your specific question *"How to get text from Entry"*, you need to call the `get` method. The flaw in your code is that you aren't calling the get method. You need to change `printValues` to look like the following. Notice the use of `()` after `get`:

```
def printValues(self):
    print(self.firstname.get())
```

However, that exposes the next problem in your code. You're making the same type of mistake when you create `self.firstname`. You need to change it to the following. Again, notice the use of `()`.

```
self.firstname = StringVar()
```

The third problem is that you can only do that after first creating the root window. Your example doesn't show if, how, or when you do that, but in the comments you reported an error that is a symptom of this type of mistake.

So, before you create an instance of `StrWnd` you must create the root window. For example, it might look like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
strwnd = StrWnd()
```

Though, you seem to have another class that represents the root window so that's probably not exactly how you'll do it in your code. The point is, the root window needs to be created before you create an instance of `StringVar`.

Comment: well its working now i guess. But for some reason the print is just blank.

Comment: When I make those changes to your exact code, and add the other few bits to make it work, it works for me. Are you creating more than once instance of `Tk`?

Comment: It is working now. I had simply forgotten to add the root to the Toplevel. Thank you so much. Its already midnight now and I can finally go to sleep without breaking my head about this

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new to coding myself, but the first issue I spot is that it would have to be `tk.StringVar()` or `StringVar()` as this is not merely a variable but a predefined class in Tkinter.

To find out more, see this post: [what is the difference between a variable and StringVar() of tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783852/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-stringvar-of-tkinter/51785046)

Besides, I am not sure if all your functions are called correctly. In the last line, I would expect `self.firstname.get()` rather than `self.firstname.get`.

I am certain, however, that more experienced coders can give you much more helpful advice.

EDIT: Good to see that someone has just given you a much more detailed response already. :-)