# Convert numbers from a text field (in a GUI) into an integer in Python-3

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem that I cannot convert the input from the text box in my GUI to an integer.
The fully code (because I don't know where the problem is) is:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.wm_title("ggT berechnen")
master.config(background = "#FFFFAA") # Hintergrundfarbe des Fensters
Label(master, text="X-Wert").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Y-Wert").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def ggT(X = e1.get(), Y = e2.get()):
    X = int(X)
    Y = int(Y)
    while(X != Y):
        if X > Y:
            X, Y = X - Y, Y
        else:
            Y, X = Y - X, X
    print( X )

buttonFrame = Frame(master)
buttonFrame.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

B1 = Button(buttonFrame, text="ggT", bg="#FF0000", width=15, command=ggT)
B1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

mainloop()
```

I cannot convert the string to an integer.
Can someone please help me there?

The second question I have is:
How can I have the output of the ggT function in another text field of the GUI?
It would be very nice if I could be helped there too, thanks.

Comment: Give this a try. Insert as parameter of the function just e1 and e2, than write X = int(e1.get()) and Y = not(e2.get()). I think this could fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Question**

Issue is Python default are evaluated once when the function is defined (i.e. not dynamically when the function is called).

So you have to explicitly assign X and Y

Change:

```
def ggT(X = e1.get(), Y = e2.get()):
```

To:

```
def ggT():
    X = e1.get()
    Y = e2.get()
```

**Second Question**

One approach is connecting [StringVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783852/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-stringvar-of-tkinter/51785046)  to the text of a label.  This allows changing the label text as follows.

*Code*

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.wm_title("ggT berechnen")
master.config(background = "#FFFFAA") # Hintergrundfarbe des Fensters
Label(master, text="X-Wert").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Y-Wert").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Z-Wert").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

# Label with StringVar text associated
text = StringVar()  
e3 = Label(master, textvariable = text)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

def ggT():
    X, Y = e1.get(), e2.get()

    # convert to int and 
    # use absolute value to handle case of X or Y negative
    X, Y = abs(int(X)), abs(int(Y))

    if min(X, Y) > 0: # abs(X) and abs(Y) > 0 
                      # avoids infinite loop
        while(X != Y):
            if X > Y:
                X, Y = X - Y, Y
            else:
                Y, X = Y - X, X

        # update label with X
        text.set(str(X))
    else:
        text.set('X and Y must be non-zero')
    
buttonFrame = Frame(master)
buttonFrame.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

B1 = Button(buttonFrame, text="ggT", bg="#FF0000", width=15, command=ggT)
B1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd also check that both X and Y are greater than zero before starting the loop.

Comment: @TlsChris--good point.  Change to use the absolute values to handle X or Y negative.

Comment: More like`if min( X,Y) < 1: text.set('Invalid values'); return` X or Y of zero creates an infinite loop.

Comment: @TlsChris-how about neither X or Y can be zero (consider I'm using abs(X) and abs(Y)) in while loop?  See the updated answer.