# Simple Login Page Program Yields an Attribute Error in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm working on a simple "login page" program using tkinter. Basically all it does is it checks whether the given username and password match to an entry in a regular python dictionary. However, when I try clicking the Login button, I get an error which looks like this:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "LoginRegister.py", line 26, in login
    if username_entry_login.get() in database:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

database = {
    "Username" : "123"
}

# Creating the login page
def login_page():
    global username_entry_login
    global password_entry_login

    login_screen = Tk()
    login_screen.title("Login")
    Label(login_screen, text="Username:").pack()
    username_entry_login = Entry(login_screen).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Password:").pack()
    password_entry_login = Entry(login_screen, show="*").pack()
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", command=login).pack()
    access_label = Label(login_screen, text="").pack()


# Creating the function for the login button
def login():
    if username_entry_login.get() in database:
        if database[username_entry_login.get()] == password_entry_login.get():
            access_label.config(text="Access Granted")
        else:
            access_label.config(text="Access Denied")
    else:
        access_label.config(text="Access Denied")

# Creating the main page
Button(text="Login", command=login_page).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Is `username_entry_login` a string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because the `.pack()` method is called on the Entry box and the result is stored in `username_entry_login` which does not have a `.get` method. You can either separate the `.pack()` from the creation of the widget or use special text widgets known as [[string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783852/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-stringvar-of-tkinter/51785046)]

Option 1 - Separating the `.pack()` method from the initialization of the Entry widget

Something like:

```
username_entry_login = Entry(login_screen)
username_entry_login.pack()
username_entry_login.get() # returns the the contents of the username entry box
```

Option 2 - String Variables

Something like:

```
username_strvar = StringVar()
Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_strvar).pack()
```

Then you can `.get()` the string variable's value which will return as a string, the contents of the Entry box.

So:

```
username_strvar.get() # returns the contents of the username entry box
```

Comment: tkinter `Entry` widget has `get()` function.  The issue is `username_entry_login` is the result of `pack()` (`username_entry_login = Entry(login_screen).pack()`) which is `None`, not an instance of `Entry`.

Comment: Oh my bad, fixing the post

Comment: Aah, got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: For option 2, you don't need the variable `username_entry_login` as it is `None` as well.