# Unable to get entry in tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to grab an input from an entry using tkinter in python. In theory, I should click the 'upload' button, then the code will get the entry and print it for me, but this isn't working. This is my code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def cancel():
    quit()

def upload():
    Entry.get()
    print(Entry)



bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

whitebutton = Entry(frame, fg="black")
whitebutton.pack( side = TOP)

redbutton = Button(frame, text="Cancel", fg="red", command = cancel)
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

bluebutton = Button(frame, text="Upload URL", fg="blue", command = upload)
bluebutton.pack( side = RIGHT )

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?
Thanks, Kieran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entry` is a class in `__init__` file in tkinter folder.

Instead of this:

```
Entry.get()
print(Entry)
```

This is what you need

```
var=whitebutton.get()
print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is better to use Tkinter variables rather than normal python variables. Here you need to use `StringVar()` to set and get an user input from entry. So the complete code -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def cancel():
    quit()

def upload():
    print(var.get())



bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

whitebutton = Entry(frame,textvariable=var ,fg="black")
whitebutton.pack( side = TOP)

redbutton = Button(frame, text="Cancel", fg="red", command = cancel)
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

bluebutton = Button(frame, text="Upload URL", fg="blue", command = upload)
bluebutton.pack( side = RIGHT )

root.mainloop()
```

For more info - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783852/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-stringvar-of-tkinter/51785046) and [this](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_variable_classes.php)

Answer (score -1):

put **root** var before root.mainloop() 
and make **app** var and put into "Application(root)" 
then change ""root".mainloop()" to "app.mainlop()"

```
import tkinter as tk

// your code

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can you do that

Comment: First of all there are no classes in the program. OP is opting for a functional based program