# What the purpose of a StringVar name in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, var

When I create a `StringVar` like so:

```py
myvar = StringVar(master, "value", "name")
```

What is the purpose of the last parameter? What benefit do we get by "naming" the `StringVar`, and how can we use that name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between a variable and StringVar() of tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783852/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-stringvar-of-tkinter)

Comment: Not, this explaine about the StringVar, things that I already know, but not explain the purpose of its name.

Comment: The *name* is used by the underlying TCL interpreter to refer the internal variable created. If not given, the tkinter module will create one implicitly.

Comment: oh yes, I understand. So for us its don't change anything, it's only a internal utility, right?

Comment: You can use the *name* to get or set the value using internal functions, for example `root.globalgetvar("name")` where `root` is the root window.  You can replace `root` with the name of any instance of tkinter widget.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that, thank you very much! It will help me a lot!

Comment: @acw1668 I can't find a duplicate for this, and I've edited the question for clarity. Would you mind writing a full answer?